# Access Values In Nested Array in JSON response

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional JSON array returned via a web request (http://www.coincap.io/history/365day/BTC). I want to cycle through the 2nd entry and retrieve its nested values.

If this was a normal array, I'd use:

```
For Each item In response
    logic, logic, logic

    currentRow = currentRow + 1
Next
```

This web request returns a JSON-response with 3 entries: market_cap, price, and volume. I just want to cycle through `response(1)` and get the price values. Each entry in `price` contains two keys, `0` and `1`.

I would imagine that I could accomplish this by doing

```
For Each item in response(1)
    Cells(currentRow, 1).Value = item(0)
    Cells(currentRow, 2).Value = item(1)

    currentRow = currentRow + 1
Next
```

I've also considered `For Each item in response("price")`. Neither works.

Comment: Please show/describe exactly how you got to your `response` object. Are you using a JSON-parsing library/class?  If Yes, which one?  If No then....?  It's much easier for folk to help you if you provide a working set of code to get them at least as far as you have got.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim json As String
    Dim sc As Object
    Dim o, n, i, p

    Set sc = CreateObject("scriptcontrol")
    sc.Language = "JScript"

    json = HttpGet("http://www.coincap.io/history/365day/BTC")

    sc.Eval "var obj=(" & json & ")" 'evaluate the json response
    'add a couple of accessor functions
    sc.AddCode "function numPrices(){return obj.price.length;}"
    sc.AddCode "function getPrice(i){return obj.price[i];}"

    n = sc.Run("numPrices")
    For i = 0 To n - 1
        p = Split(sc.Run("getPrice", i), ",")
        Debug.Print i, p(0), p(1)
    Next i

End Sub

Function HttpGet(url As String) As String
    Dim oHTML As Object
    Set oHTML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    With oHTML
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        HttpGet = .responsetext
    End With
End Function
```